# Error while deploying React app on Heroku, no error in log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

I tried to deploy a React app I made which was running perfectly fine on Netlify, but I am facing some Application Error. There is no error code in the logs (at least none which I saw). This is the first time I'm deploying an app on Heroku for the first time. Screenshots attached.

[Part 1 of log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGMdY.png)

[Part 2 of log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3AU7.png)

[Console errors and homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBeTx.png)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Build logs provided.

````
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.18.1...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.5
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       > core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /tmp/build_5edb6d3e93243b9a21809f4233b8fd96/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
       
       > fsevents@1.2.12 install /tmp/build_5edb6d3e93243b9a21809f4233b8fd96/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents
       > node-gyp rebuild
       
       make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_5edb6d3e93243b9a21809f4233b8fd96/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents/build'
         SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/.node
         COPY Release/.node
       make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_5edb6d3e93243b9a21809f4233b8fd96/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents/build'
       
       > fsevents@1.2.12 install /tmp/build_5edb6d3e93243b9a21809f4233b8fd96/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents
       > node-gyp rebuild
       
       make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_5edb6d3e93243b9a21809f4233b8fd96/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents/build'
         SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/.node
         COPY Release/.node
       make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_5edb6d3e93243b9a21809f4233b8fd96/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents/build'
       
       > core-js@3.6.5 postinstall /tmp/build_5edb6d3e93243b9a21809f4233b8fd96/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
       
       > fsevents@1.2.12 install /tmp/build_5edb6d3e93243b9a21809f4233b8fd96/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents
       > node-gyp rebuild
       
       make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_5edb6d3e93243b9a21809f4233b8fd96/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents/build'
         SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/.node
         COPY Release/.node
       make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_5edb6d3e93243b9a21809f4233b8fd96/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents/build'
       
       > core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall /tmp/build_5edb6d3e93243b9a21809f4233b8fd96/node_modules/core-js-pure
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
       added 1703 packages in 40.625s
       
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > track-covid-19@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_5edb6d3e93243b9a21809f4233b8fd96
       > react-scripts build
       
       Creating an optimized production build...
       Compiled with warnings.
       
       ./src/components/Navbar.js
         Line 20:9:   The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
         Line 24:11:  The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
         Line 25:11:  The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
         Line 27:11:  The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
       
       ./src/pages/About.js
         Line 2:10:  'Cards' is defined but never used          no-unused-vars
         Line 2:17:  'Chart' is defined but never used          no-unused-vars
         Line 2:24:  'CountryPicker' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
         Line 3:8:   'styles' is defined but never used         no-unused-vars
         Line 4:10:  'fetchData' is defined but never used      no-unused-vars
       
       ./src/App.js
         Line 2:10:  'Cards' is defined but never used          no-unused-vars
         Line 2:17:  'Chart' is defined but never used          no-unused-vars
         Line 2:24:  'CountryPicker' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
         Line 3:8:   'styles' is defined but never used         no-unused-vars
         Line 7:32:  'Link' is defined but never used           no-unused-vars
       
       Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
       To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
       
       File sizes after gzip:
       
         157.04 KB  build/static/js/2.195d9dd8.chunk.js
         4.34 KB    build/static/js/main.b71afa7e.chunk.js
         779 B      build/static/js/runtime-main.b8bd243b.js
         396 B      build/static/css/main.6cf0b677.chunk.css
       
       The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
       You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
       
       The build folder is ready to be deployed.
       You may serve it with a static server:
       
         npm install -g serve
         serve -s build
       
       Find out more about deployment here:
       
         bit.ly/CRA-deploy
       
       
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       audited 1901 packages in 15.118s
       
       65 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 2 vulnerabilities (1 low, 1 high)
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 71.5M
-----> Launching...
       Released v5
       https://corona-tracker-19.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku  ```
````

Comment: You should insert the code/logs here, rather than attaching an image url which may expire over time.

Comment: You haven't provided any logs. You screenshotted different pages of Heroku explaining to you how to get the logs.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've provided the build logs. Is there anything else needed to be provided?